# Swift/FireStore - Add and update sub-collection at fixed path

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a review system. I am not adding the actual review in this sub-collection, rather I will store reviews with comments at a separate index. However, I wish to add the ratings. I have two ratings - one for experience and the other for product. Ratings are from 1-5.

I was thinking of adding just the rating (ints) at this following path

```
user -> user_document -> ratings -> [auto_id] -> xpRating = [0: 5]
```

I would just create an array of the ratings, so that I can count how many ratings there are but also get the average value of all ratings to display to the user.

However, the issue is the auto id. I'd much rather prefer:

```
user -> user_document -> ratings -> userXpRating -> xpRating = [0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 4]
```

I would prefer to have a fixed location and keep updating the values. As this data will be shown when the user profile is displayed. So for indexing and hopefully time, this would prove to be better.

I know Firebase has a collection limit of 20,000 but that's neither here or there, for now.

How can I eliminate the auto-id and continue to append to the specific location?

When I create the user account, initially, this path/collection isn't defined.